# preg_replace(): Compilation failed

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is anyone here who can help me with this?
the pattern is

```
/\[url=?\]([a-z0-9:\.\\\/-\s]*?)\[\/url\]/isS
```

The error:

> preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 26

Comment: Which is character 26?

Answer (score 1):

Escape minus (-)

```
 /\[url=?\]([a-z0-9:\.\\\/\-\s]*?)\[\/url\]/is
```

[**Demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/uR0hR8/2)

Comment: Thx. get the same warning now at offset 23 and with a changed pattern. 
The new pattern is now: /\[url=([a-z0-9:\.\\\/-\s]+?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/isS Thats what it makes out of yours.

Comment: look demo in my answer

Answer (score 1):

This should work in PHP (PCRE):

```
/\[url=?\]([a-z0-9:\.\\\/\-\s]*?)\[\/url\]/is
```

First of all escape the `-` in your character class statement `[]` otherwise you get a wrong range error.

Second the `/S` modifier is probably not a good idea with your pattern. Read:

> When a pattern is going to be used several times, it is worth spending
>   more time analyzing it in order to speed up the time taken for
>   matching. If this modifier is set, then this extra analysis is
>   performed. At present, studying a pattern is useful only for
>   non-anchored patterns that do not have a single fixed starting
>   character.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

To test your regular expressions [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is quite good.